# ArrayList and initializing a 2D array not working?

Tags: arrays, arraylist

I'm learning the AP CSA course and tried to print these arrays. It keeps saying "can't find symbol" and not gonna lie I have absolutely no idea what that means.

```
//ArrayList:
    public class al{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            List l = new ArrayList();
            System.out.print(l.size());
        }
    }
```

```
//2DArray:
    public class arrays{
       public static void main(String[] args){
          int[][] arry =  {{1,2,3}, 
                           {1,2,3}, 
                           {1,2,3}};
          printArray(arry);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first program to print the ArrayList, it is failing because you need to import the List and ArrayList in your program, please try this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class al{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List l = new ArrayList();
        System.out.print(l.size());
    }
}
```

In the second program the printArray method you called is missing in definition, i.e you have to define the printArray method in your class, you are using it from method main then you need to declare it static like below

```
static void printArray(int[][] arr){
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        String row = "";
        for(int j=0; j<arr[0].length;j++){
            row+=arr[i][j]+" ";
        }
        System.out.println(row);
    }
}
```

Also while you are learning, please also read about the naming conventions in java (i suppose you are learning java), like a Class name should start from a capital letter.